# Dynamically linking 3 Tkinter Scale widgets so that their sum is always 1

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

So I'm new to coding, but I'm attempting to make my first full application. My goal is to have three Tkinter scale widgets representing the probability/weight of each corresponding note (either a plucked note, explicit silence, or a sustained note) showing up in a randomly generated rhythm. That being said, NumPy's Random module requires that all three probabilities must equal one - however, I do still want to keep the default starting value.

I've tried using the `.get()` and `.set()` methods extensively as well as the Scale Variable, all to no avail.
It's been a few days and my brain hurts. I can't get any of them to link dynamically whatsoever. Do I need a more OOP approach maybe?

I've stripped all functionality and unnecessary GUI elements to help isolate the problem:

```
from tkinter import *

# def notes_comp():
#   summ = (float(silence_weight.get()))+(float(sustain_weight.get()))
#   diff = 1 - (float(note_weight.get())+summ)
#   if float(note1_weight.get())+summ != 1:
#       silence_weight.set(silence_weight.get()+diff/2)
#       sustain_weight.set(sustain_weight.get()+diff/2)

def notes_comp(value):
    notes_weight = var_1.set("value")
    silence_set = var_2.get()
    sustain_set = var_3.get()
    for i in range(1 - notes_weight):
        silence_set += .5*(1 - var_1.get())
        sustain_set += .5*(1 - var_1.get())


# tkinter GUI
root = Tk(className=" Rhythm Generator")
# setting color variables
bg_color = "#1c1c1c"
rollover_color = "#d9d9d9"
var_1 = DoubleVar()
var_2 = DoubleVar()
var_3 = DoubleVar()
root.configure(bg=bg_color)

# creating master frames
top_frame = Frame(root, bg=bg_color)
top_frame.grid(row="0")

# creating sliders
note1_weight = Scale(top_frame, from_="1", to="0", resolution=".1", variable="var_1", command="notes_comp")
note1_weight.grid(column="2", row="0")
silence_weight = Scale(top_frame, from_="1", to="0", resolution=".1", variable="var_2")
silence_weight.grid(column="3", row="0")
sustain_weight = Scale(top_frame, from_="1", to="0", resolution=".1", variable="var_3")
sustain_weight.grid(column="4", row="0")
note1_weight.set(.1)
silence_weight.set(.1)
sustain_weight.set(.8)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: BWT: you have to use function's name in `command=notes_comp`, not string `"notes_comp"`.

Comment: BTW: if you want to use `value` to set `var_1` then you have to use variable `value`, not string `"value"` - `var_1.set(value)`. But `var_1.set(value)` returns `None` so using `notes_weight = var_1.set(value)` is useless because it works like `var_1.set(value)` and `notes_weight = None`

Comment: BTW: you have to use variable `var_1`, not strings `"var_1"` in `variable=var_1`

Comment: BTW: standard `range()` works only with integer values but in `range(1-notes_weight)` you will get float value in `1 - notes_weight`. Maybe instead of float values 0...1 in range you should use integer values `0..10` - `range(int(10 - notes_weight*10))` - and later use `i/10` to get float value for other calculations.

Answer (score 1):

This code resolve some problem with running `notes_comp` when you move `Scale` but it not resolve problem to keep sum of all values equal 1.

In all situation you have to use variables, not strings `"var_1"` and `"notes_comp"`

```
variable=var_1, command=notes_comp
```

---

For every `Scale` I use two `DoubleVar` - `current_var` and `previous_var` so I can compare how it changed and try to use difference `current_var - previous_var` to change other values. But this is problem because I can't add `(current_var - previous_var)/2` to both because one of them may have already maximal value. Other problem is that `(current_var - previous_var)/2` may gives value `0.05` but `Scale` has `resolution=".1"` so it can't display `0.05`, `0.15`, `0.25`, etc . If I would change `resolution=".05"` then `(current_var - previous_var)/2` would give value `0.025` and `Scale` would not dosplay `0.025`, `0.075`, `0.125`, etc.

Other problem makes (as usually) `float` values which sometimes give different results then we could expect - ie. `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` gives `False` but we could expect `True` - because computer keeps only some aproximations.

```
from tkinter import *

# def notes_comp():
#   summ = (float(silence_weight.get()))+(float(sustain_weight.get()))
#   diff = 1 - (float(note_weight.get())+summ)
#   if float(note1_weight.get())+summ != 1:
#       silence_weight.set(silence_weight.get()+diff/2)
#       sustain_weight.set(sustain_weight.get()+diff/2)

def notes_comp(value):
    #
    # this calculations doesn't work correctly
    #

    print('running notes_comp:')

    # compare difference - minimal value `0.1`
    diff = current_var_1.get() - previous_var_1.get()

    # sometimes `half1` can be `0.0` and then `half2 has to be `0.1` instead of `0.05`
    half1 = round(diff/2, 1)
    half2 = round(diff-half1, 1)
    #print(previous_var_1.get(), current_var_1.get(), half1, half2)

    # use it to change other valus
    current_var_2.set(current_var_2.get() - half1)
    current_var_3.set(current_var_3.get() - half2)

    # remember current value to use it next time
    previous_var_1.set(current_var_1.get())


# tkinter GUI
root = Tk(className=" Rhythm Generator")
# setting color variables
bg_color = "#1c1c1c"
rollover_color = "#d9d9d9"

current_var_1 = DoubleVar()
current_var_2 = DoubleVar()
current_var_3 = DoubleVar()

previous_var_1 = DoubleVar()
previous_var_2 = DoubleVar()
previous_var_3 = DoubleVar()

root.configure(bg=bg_color)

# creating master frames
top_frame = Frame(root, bg=bg_color)
top_frame.grid(row="0")

# creating sliders
note1_weight = Scale(top_frame, from_="1", to="0", resolution=".1", variable=current_var_1, command=notes_comp)
note1_weight.grid(column="2", row="0")

silence_weight = Scale(top_frame, from_="1", to="0", resolution=".1", variable=current_var_2)
silence_weight.grid(column="3", row="0")

sustain_weight = Scale(top_frame, from_="1", to="0", resolution=".1", variable=current_var_3)
sustain_weight.grid(column="4", row="0")

# start values
current_var_1.set(.1)
previous_var_1.set(.1)

current_var_2.set(.1)
previous_var_2.set(.1)

current_var_3.set(.8)
previous_var_3.set(.8)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the Scale widget command callback functions are called whenever the Scale widgets change, the callbacks must be 'switched off' as widgets are set to avoid an infinite sequence of calls to the callback functions as a change to widget 1 affects widget 2 & 3.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
top_frame = tk.Frame(root, padx = 10, pady = 10 ).grid()
root.title('3 Scales')

top_frame = tk.Frame(root, padx = 10, pady = 10 ).grid()

# Column headers
for col, txt in enumerate([ 'Note 1', 'Silence', 'Sustain' ]):
    tk.Label( text = txt).grid( row = 0, column = col )

# Create & grid Scale widgets
note1_weight = tk.Scale(top_frame, from_= 1, to= 0, resolution = 0.01 )
note1_weight.grid(column=0, row=2)

silence_weight = tk.Scale(top_frame, from_= 1, to= 0, resolution = 0.01 )
silence_weight.grid(column=1, row=2)

sustain_weight = tk.Scale(top_frame, from_= 1, to= 0, resolution= 0.01 )
sustain_weight.grid(column=2, row=2)

# Initialise the widgets
note1_weight.set(0.34)
silence_weight.set(0.33)
sustain_weight.set(0.33)

# Container for the command functions
# Filled after make_command is defined.
command_func = [ 0 ] * 3

def commands_activate():
    """ makes all the command functions active """
    note1_weight.config( command = command_func[0] )
    silence_weight.config( command = command_func[1] )
    sustain_weight.config( command = command_func[2] )

def commands_deactivate():
    """ Stops all the command functions being called """
    note1_weight.config( command = "" )
    silence_weight.config( command = "" )
    sustain_weight.config( command = "" )

def make_command( other0, other1 ):
    """ Generates a command function thar updates the 'other' two Scale widgets.
        Using the closure avoids writing 3 almost identcal functions
    """
    def cmd( pos ):
        """ A command callback function which updates widgets
            other0 and other1 as the current widget changes.
        """
        commands_deactivate()           
        # Stop the .set(..) in this function triggering further calls to cmd

        ########################################################################
        # This section of code performs the sum == 1.0 calculations
        # It can be changed to allocate the diff as required.
        # Here it prorates the difference from 1.0 across the other two widgets

        diff = 1.0 - float(pos)
        v0 = max( other0.get(), 0.0001)  # If both v0 and v1 == 0.0 there's no prorating
        v1 = max( other1.get(), 0.0001)  # so ensure v0 and v1 are never precisely zero.
        fact = diff / ( v0 + v1 )
        other0.set( v0 * fact )
        other1.set( v1 * fact )
        ########################################################################

        commands_activate()
        # Then reactivate the commands

    return cmd

# Generate the three command functions
command_func[0] = make_command( silence_weight, sustain_weight )
command_func[1] = make_command( note1_weight, sustain_weight )
command_func[2] = make_command( note1_weight, silence_weight )

# Activate the command functions before mainloop
commands_activate()

root.mainloop()
```